# too much recursion error while form submit in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting error of "too much recursion" while form submit, here is my code can anyone  please tell me what is issue ?

```
$("#ajax-post-form").on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
            var postType = $("#post-posttype").val();
            var postVideo = $("#post-postvideo").val();
            var postImages = $("#post-postimages").val();
            if(postVideo == '' && postType == 3) {
                alert("Please upload video");
                return false;
            }
            else if(postType == '1' || postType == '2') {
                if(postType == '2' && postImages == '') {
                    alert("Please upload image");
                    return false;
                }  else {
                    $("#spinnerLoader").show();  
                    $("#ajax-post-form").submit();
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condensing down to a minimal working example...

```
$("#ajax-post-form").on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {            
    $("#ajax-post-form").submit(); //triggers 'beforeSubmit' event and causes recursion
})
```

You might want to unhook your `beforeSubmit` handler before your attempt to resubmit...

...or add a flag to indicate resubmission:

```
var resubmit = false;
$("#ajax-post-form").on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {    
    if(resubmit)return;
    resubmit = true;
    $("#ajax-post-form").submit(); //this triggers 'beforeSubmit' event
    resubmit = false;
})
```